# How to generate a dynamic ViewBinding?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-jetpack

I'm generating a dynamic custom view (changes the layout depending on the input that the user chooses) that extends from ConstraintLayout like this:

```
            class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
                context: Context,
                attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                defStyleAttr: Int = 0
            ) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        
    init{
        var layout = when{
           1 -> R.layout.layout1
           2 -> R.layout.layout2
           3 -> R.layout.layout3
           else -> R.layout.layout4   
       }        
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layout, this, true)
    }
```

I want to implement view binding in this custom view, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by implement view binding in this view? That could be interpreted several different ways. The code you shared doesn't make sense because there's no subject for the `when`

Comment: @Tenfour04 I know it doesn't make sense, I'm just giving context of what I want
// This is somehow what I want to achieve `binding = CustomViewBinding.inflate(layout))
        `

Comment: I mentioned it because knowing if this is based on something determined at runtime or compile time would help to suggest a solution. Are you just wanting to use view binding inside your custom class code? You will need a separate binding property for each of the possible layouts, which means in any particular instance of the class, most of the bindings will be null. It would be kind of messy. Unfortunately there's no way to make all these bindings implement a common interface even if they have children with the same IDs.

Comment: Well, I'm also having problems finding the binding classes for each layout.xml, Gradle is not generating them, I think that was a signal that this wasn't going to work:(

Comment: That’s irrelevant to whether you can use binding in your custom class. If view binding is working at all, you can use it in any class as long as you have a reference to a Context to pass to its inflate function. Sounds like a view binding setup problem, or maybe you aren’t using the expected name of your binding classes. Binding classes are named after the xml files, not whatever class you’re using them in.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for the dynamic create fragment screen on the base fragment class.

private lateinit var emailBinding: FragmentCreateEmailBinding // code in EmailFragment.

```
override fun getViewChild(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?): View? 
 {
    emailBinding = FragmentCreateEmailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return emailBinding.root
}
```

After that, you can use emailBinding.edtTo or something like View Binding tutorial.
This is my code for the custom layout in each case. In the BaseFragment getViewChild() return the view so I can use addView(getViewChild()). Hope you can understand.